# Is there a way for SLEEP() in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sleep

I have a *stored procedure* I'd like to run forever, but sleep for one second in a loop. When it wakes up it would poll a table to see if it should do some work.  Work only needs to be done every minute, so there is no worry about the poll table getting hit with updates from two writers at the same time.

What is the best way to `SLEEP()` for an interval in a *stored procedure*?  It would be nice, actually, if it could sleep for 200 milliseconds, but one second would work too.

Comment: Isn't there a scheduling facility in the database? Even MySQL has one.

Comment: I dont know..  is there?  I'm not sure how easy this would be to implement a sleep() facility inside the database.  It would actually, thinking about it, be extremely difficult.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: @chris, that's neat! Can you flesh that out into an answer the OP can use?

Comment: @BarryBrown, I've yet to use that feature, I was just aware of its existence.

Answer (score 29):

I've encountered the same problem. After googling a lot, I found out that we can use

```
SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);
```

to delay our procedures for this many seconds. In your case, using

```
SELECT SLEEP(0.2);
```

would be just fine.

Comment: Also, if you don't need de results of the query (wich you probably not, as the select sleep() just brings a 0) you can use "DO SLEEP(<seconds>);"

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
DO SLEEP(0.2);
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/do.html

or

```
SELECT SLEEP(0.2);
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has an event scheduler baked in. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html

Sample:

```
CREATE EVENT performance_schema_snapshots.fill_events_statements_summary_by_digest_history1
  ON SCHEDULE -- every day at 6 am 
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 14 HOUR
  DO
    -- take snapshot 
    CALL performance_schema_snapshots.events_statements_summary_by_digest_snapshot_reset ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont specify which database you are using, but generally the way to achive what you want is not to have an infinetly running sproc but to have some external component - like a scheduler, or SQL Server Agent in MSSQL - execute the sproc every so often.

Comment: database is mysql.  yes - I would have an external process run this every so often if there is no way to do it inside the DB.